# Cannot get advanced mining laser from outpost

Tags: no-mans-sky

Interacting with the outpost NPC tagged by the Specialist does not trigger the proper dialog to obtain the `advanced mining laser`.

Comment: Is this the Exosuit advanced mining laser or the one for Exocraft?

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you find the outpost before the Specialist tags it for you.

The only workaround I've found is to resettle Home Base in a different system, losing all the construction work.

Some resources are salvaged, and progress is kept.  Hired specialists are kept on roster.

See also http://steamcommunity.com/app/275850/discussions/4/154642321534059928/